# Why RecyclerviewItemBinding Class can not be found in android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use the ViewBinding in the
MainAdapter Class but Android Studio can not find the **RecyclerviewItemBinding Class**.(I also used the buildFeatures)

```
class MainAdapter(val taskList: List<TaskModel>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.MainViewHolder>() {

    inner class MainViewHolder(val itemBinding: **RecyclerviewItemBinding**) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added `buildFeatures { viewBinding true }` in your app ;even `build.gradle`? If so, then try clearing the cache & rebuild project from `Build > Clean > Rebuild`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work